# Android making a ToggleButton to set the Ringtone to Vibrate

Tags: android, volume, seek, vibration

I am currently making an app with a SeekBar in which the SeekBar controls the Music Volume, Ringtone Volume, and Alarm Volume. It works fine but whenever I try to code in a button to set the phone to vibrate, it either crashes the app or it just breaks the code so the SeekBar never changes the volumes. Any help on how to achieve a button to set the phone to vibrate will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
   import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private SeekBar Volume = null;
    private AudioManager audioManager = null;
    private TextView volumeValue;
    private Vibrator sVibrate;
    private ToggleButton vibrateButton;
    final private String volumeIs = "Current Volume: ";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        allVolumes();
    }

    private void allVolumes()
    {
        try
        {
            Volume = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.Volume);
            audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            Volume.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            Volume.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

            sVibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrateButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.vibrateButton);

            volumeValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.volumeValue);
            volumeValue.setText(volumeIs
                    + Integer.toString(audioManager
                            .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)));

            Volume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0)
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress,
                        boolean arg2)
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                            progress, 0);
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
                            progress, 0);

                    volumeValue.setText(volumeIs
                            + Integer.toString(audioManager
                                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)));
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.catch_error);
            builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Quit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Ignore",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(
                                    MainActivity.this,
                                    "This app will not work right unless you restart.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any help on how to achieve a button to set the phone to vibrate will be greatly appreciated.

Do you mean, switch the phone to the vibration mode? Try this:

```
(AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```